# Configurable product Magento 2

Tags: e-commerce, product, magento2

I'm starting to mess with magento 2, and I'm finding it difficult in some respects, such as in configurable product, I create a color product the same color plus different size and when I select both sizes it adds two values as if I was buying two products and not only different size.
Example
I am buying a bikini that has bust and thong, the color and only type Red, plus we have the size of the bust that can be P, M and G I select the M and now I will buy the thong that has sizes P, M and G I I select G, it's a single product with a single value $ 160 I just have to tell you what size I want, more when I create the configurable product and I'll do the test by selecting the sizes that it says now it selects how two products generate a value of  $ 320.
My question is how can I solve this problem.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When creating new configurable product in magento 2, under Configurations there is a button named Create Configurations when clicked, it asks you to choose which attributes are to use. After choosing magento asks which options to use, these attributes and options combinations are all become a simple product that generated from a configurable product. For example, if you crate a bikini as a configurable product, and you choose size and color as configuration attribute and for instance red, blue and black color options and 36, 37 and 38 size options. After creation magento will create 9 products with all attribute combinations. And on product detail on frontend, you should see 3 color option and 3 size option . For example if you choose black and 38 size and add to cart you added 38 size black color bikini to your cart.
I hope this answer helps.